# load csv in neo4j got java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded exception

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I tried to load csv data into embedded neo4j database(v2.1.7、on windows). The csv file has 1,000,000 rows(1 Million). And data model is simple too. just as following:

### csv data

```
"num1","num2","datatime"
"13931345724","18409958023","2014-12-31 12:00:00"
"13931345724","13710622859","2014-12-31 12:00:00"
"13931345724","18919875049","2014-12-31 12:00:00"
"13931345724","13460873081","2014-12-31 12:00:00"
...
```

### loading cypher sql

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000 
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:C:/tmpFiles/calls100w.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR ','
 WITH line 
MERGE (n0:Phone:_Phone {phoneNumber : line[0]}) 
MERGE (n1:Phone:_Phone {phoneNumber : line[1]}) 
MERGE (n0)-[:CALL{callAt: line[2]}]->(n1)
```

And this took a long time and got this exception:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I tried to add **neo4j-wrapper.conf** file in the database location folder.
but it seemed to have no effect.

### neo4j-wrapper.conf

```
wrapper.java.additional.1=-XX:-UseConcMarkSweepGC
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Xloggc:c:/neo4jdb/log/neo4j-gc.log
wrapper.java.initmemory=4096
wrapper.java.maxmemory=4096
```

And here was what showed in messages.log file

```
2015-06-09 09:55:00.513+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: System memory information:
    Total Physical memory: 7.70 GB
    Free Physical memory: 1.99 GB
    Committed virtual memory: 361.05 MB
    Total swap space: 14.48 GB
    Free swap space: 5.76 GB
2015-06-09 09:55:00.519+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: JVM memory information:
    Free  memory: 135.42 MB
    Total memory: 148.94 MB
    Max   memory: 1.71 GB
    Garbage Collector: PS Scavenge: [PS Eden Space, PS Survivor Space]
    Garbage Collector: PS MarkSweep: [PS Eden Space, PS Survivor Space, PS Old Gen, PS Perm Gen]
    Memory Pool: Code Cache (Non-heap memory): committed=2.44 MB, used=833.00 kB, max=48.00 MB, threshold=0.00 B
    Memory Pool: PS Eden Space (Heap memory): committed=61.63 MB, used=7.28 MB, max=647.06 MB, threshold=?
    Memory Pool: PS Survivor Space (Heap memory): committed=5.13 MB, used=5.12 MB, max=5.13 MB, threshold=?
    Memory Pool: PS Old Gen (Heap memory): committed=82.19 MB, used=1.12 MB, max=1.28 GB, threshold=0.00 B
    Memory Pool: PS Perm Gen (Non-heap memory): committed=20.75 MB, used=12.78 MB, max=82.00 MB, threshold=0.00 B
```

On windows there is no conf/ folder in database location folder, so I made one and put neo4j-wrapper.conf in it. Have conf file been placed in the right place?

### database location folder

```
C:\NEO4JDB
|   index.db
|   messages.log
|   neo4j.properties
|   neostore
|   neostore.id
|   neostore.labeltokenstore.db
|   ....
+---conf
|       neo4j-wrapper.conf
+---index
|       lucene-store.db
|       lucene.log.active
|       ...
\---schema
    +---...
```

Comment: neo4j-wrapper.conf is located in home directory of neo4j. Together with neo4j-server.properties and neo4j.properties

Comment: @MicTech thanks for quick comment. In this case, just put neo4j-wrapper.conf in C:\NEO4JDB folder?

Comment: no, it should be in directory, where you have Neo4j installation. In NEO4JDB you have only data, not Neo4j server itself.

Comment: @MicTech Even I did not install Neo4j db, just included all necessary jar files using maven in my web app,  neo4j function worked fine. In this case, neo4j-wrapper.conf will be put in the jar folder to take effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split it into 2 Imports:

You run into the problem where cypher creates an [**Eager** pipe](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/) to assert correct separation, which causes all your CSV lines to be pulled in eagerly, rendering periodic commit effectless, see:

```
explain LOAD CSV FROM 'file:C:/tmpFiles/calls100w.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR ','
>  WITH line 
> MERGE (n0:Phone:_Phone {phoneNumber : line[0]}) 
> MERGE (n1:Phone:_Phone {phoneNumber : line[1]}) 
> MERGE (n0)-[:CALL{callAt: line[2]}]->(n1) ;
+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------+
| Operator     | Identifiers             | Other             |
+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------+
| +EmptyResult |                         |                   |
| |            +-------------------------+-------------------+
| +UpdateGraph | anon[195], line, n0, n1 | MergePattern      |
| |            +-------------------------+-------------------+
| +UpdateGraph | line, n0, n1            | MergeNode; :Phone |
| |            +-------------------------+-------------------+
| +Eager       | line, n0                |                   |
| |            +-------------------------+-------------------+
| +UpdateGraph | line, n0                | MergeNode; :Phone |
| |            +-------------------------+-------------------+
| +LoadCSV     | line                    |                   |
+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------+
```

I presume you have an index/constraint on `:Phone(phoneNumber)`.
If you split your query up into two parts it will work:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000 
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:C:/tmpFiles/calls100w.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR ','
 WITH line 
MERGE (n0:Phone:_Phone {phoneNumber : line[0]}) 
MERGE (n1:Phone:_Phone {phoneNumber : line[1]});

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000 
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:C:/tmpFiles/calls100w.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR ','
 WITH line 
MATCH (n0:Phone:_Phone {phoneNumber : line[0]}) 
MATCH (n1:Phone:_Phone {phoneNumber : line[1]}) 
MERGE (n0)-[:CALL{callAt: line[2]}]->(n1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try splitting the import into node import and relationships import. Instead of having `MERGE` statements you can just use `CREATE`, assuming that your node and relationship files are de-deduplicated.

So, for example, make a "num1.csv" file that only contains the first column (num1) of your "calls100w.csv" file and remove all of the duplicates. Make a "num2.csv" that only contains the second column of "calls100w.csv" and remove duplicates.

Then load your node csv files:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000 
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:C:/tmpFiles/num1.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR ','
WITH line 
CREATE (n0:Phone:_Phone {phoneNumber : line[0]})
```

AND

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000 
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:C:/tmpFiles/num2.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR ','
WITH line 
CREATE (n1:Phone:_Phone {phoneNumber : line[0]})
```

Then create your index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Phone(phoneNumber)
```

Now load your original csv to create the relationships:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000 
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:C:/tmpFiles/calls100w.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR ','
WITH line 
MATCH (n0:Phone:_Phone {phoneNumber : line[0]}) 
MATCH (n1:Phone:_Phone {phoneNumber : line[1]}) 
MERGE (n0)-[:CALL{callAt: line[2]}]->(n1)
```

Comment: thanks. yes, this is similar with the solution adviced by Michael Hunger.